# Question about references for proof of Proposition 1.3 in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne's article on "Tannakian Categories"

Tags: braided-tensor-categories, tannakian-category

I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 1.3 in the following article by P. Deligne & J.S. Milne: [Tannakian Categories](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2018.pdf).

They reference Saavedra Rivano's 1972 "[Catégories Tannakiennes](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059108)", but for some reason I find it very hard to parse exactly how 2.4.1 and 2.5.1 there are related to proposition 1.3. Are there any other good sources for more details regarding the proof of Proposition 1.3 in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne:s article referenced above (specifically how to see that the diagrams commute)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$Let's prove that the left square commutes (I will only give a rough sketch). This means we want to prove that the following diagram commutes
$$
\begin{CD}
X\otimes Y @>l_{X\otimes Y}>> U\otimes(X\otimes Y)\\
@VV=V @VV\phi V \\
X\otimes Y @>>l_X\otimes Y> (U\otimes X)\otimes Y.
\end{CD}
$$

By definition, $l_X\colon X\to U\otimes X$ is completely determined by $U\otimes l_X\colon U\otimes X \to U\otimes (U\otimes X)$, which in turn is defined to be the composition
$$ U\otimes X \xrightarrow{u\otimes X} (U\otimes U)\otimes X \xrightarrow{\phi^{-1}} U\otimes (U\otimes X).$$

It follows that it is enough to prove that the following diagram commutes:

$$
\begin{CD}
U\otimes(X\otimes Y) @>u\otimes (X\otimes Y)>> (U\otimes U)\otimes (X\otimes Y) @>\phi^{-1}>> U\otimes(U\otimes (X\otimes Y))\\
@VV\phi V @VV\phi V @VVV \\ 
(U\otimes X)\otimes Y @>>(u\otimes X)\otimes Y> ((U\otimes U)\otimes X)\otimes Y @>>> (U\otimes(U\otimes X))\otimes Y.
\end{CD}
$$

The left square commutes by the naturality of $\phi$. The right "square" is really a pentagon, because the right most map is really a composition of two applications of $\phi$. It is exactly the pentagon 1.0.1 on the preceding page.